# Problem with string sharing over AppDelegate-Class

Tags: objective-c, string

I'm sharing my string over the AppDelegate-Class:

```
SpeakersAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (SpeakersAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[mainDelegate setShareText:xmlString];
```

And get the string back from the AppDelegate-Class:

```
 SpeakersAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (SpeakersAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 NSString *xmlString = [mainDelegate getShareText];
```

With no problems if I use:

```
xmlString = @"<rsp><photos><photo url='xyz.jpg' thumb='xyz.jpg' /></photos></rsp>";
```

But the app crashes when I use (xmlString get's the content of the url correctly, the problem is the resiving of the string from AppDelegate-Class when xmlString is filled withContentFromURL):

```
xmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Does anyone knows a solution? Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you share some more information about the problem? What does the call stack look like at the time of the crash?

Comment: There is no crash log in console. But I've tested that when I get StringWithContentsOfURL the app crashes. But xmlString get's the content of the url correctly. NSLog shows that the string is stored correctly in AppDelegate-Variable, but crashes when I use the value returned by getShareText. But not when I set the xml-content without using url. Thanks for quick response!

Answer (score 1):

`stringWithContentsOfURL:` returns an auto-released string. So when the autorelease pool is drained (usually when it's done processing the current event), your string is released. You then try to access it, and *boom.*

I suspect that your delegate is not managing the lifecycle of xmlString. You probably want `setShareText:` to retain, or copy, the string. Be careful to release any previous string.

Comment: but why it is working then if I set the string in code? setShareText is working! NSLog shows that the value is set correctly

Comment: @pbcoder: It doesn't matter if the value is set correctly. What matters is if the object storing the value owns it. Your setter should retain the argument, but it looks like it's not doing that.

Comment: You mean xmlString = [[NSString alloc] init]?

Comment: @pbcoder, it works with the string in code because NSString literals disregard retain/release. When you call `stringWithContentsOfURL:` (which is deprecated, incidentally), you are calling a convenience method that returns an auto-released object. It actually invokes a `initWithContentsOfURL:`